# What is the byte-wise xor operation mentioned in bip 340?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, bip, math

> Let *t* be the **byte-wise xor** of *bytes(d)* and *hash_BIP0340/aux(a)*

Link: [bip-0340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki#default-signing)

Actually, I think it means [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), not bytewise xor, but for the sake of clarity, I ask: What is the difference between bytewise xor and bitwise xor?